# Codeigniter dynamic url for pages breaks routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

So in my `routes.php` file as the LAST route I have this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = '/page/index/$1';
```

This is used for dynamic pages url like `foo/dynamic-page` the problem here is that if I have a controller called `something.php` and the route will be `foo/something` and it's not manually declared in the `routes.php` file it will return a 404 because I think it will hit the `(:any)` route.

The question will be: How to make the router init a static route first before going to check dynamic page route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
$route[ 'default_controller' ]  = 'main';
$route[ '404_override' ]        = 'error404';

require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get( 'app_routes' );
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[ $row->slug ]                 = $row->controller;
    $route[ $row->slug.'/:any' ]         = $row->controller;
    $route[ $row->controller ]           = 'error404';
    $route[ $row->controller.'/:any' ]   = 'error404';
}
```

[Answer Source](http://osvaldas.info/smart-database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter)

**OR this**

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

any thing you type on the `url` will proceed to `pages/view/$1` the `$1` here is the param you wants to pass to a controller/method

```
$route['login/(:any)'] = 'show/jobs/$1';
```

you are telling CI that anything that goes to login with any parameter like `login/user` will proceed to your `show/jobs/usr` `(:any)` will match all string and integer if you use `(:num)` it will only match integer parameters like

```
$route['login/(':num')'] = 'show/jobs/$1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Routes are processed in the [order listed](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

> Note: Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

So if you (:any) is your catch all before throwing a page not found, just ensure it is placed before the (:any).

E.g.

```
$routes['foo/something'] = 'something/index';
$routes['(:any)'] = '/page/index/$1';
```

Comment: I know, but some routes aren't defined in the routes.php let's say in case of controller bikes, the route is /bikes and it doesn't need to be declared there, and this works if the (:any) route isn't there, so the problem is that I wanted it to work in both cases.